# how to hide templatefield dynamically using c#

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a Grid View now i want to hide one column using `C#`.

**Code:**

```
protected void gvLadleCleaning_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   e.Row.Cells[9].Visible = false;
}
```

**Exception:**

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection.

But currently my Grid View has 17 column.

Kindly help me to solve this problem.

Comment: It seems that your hard coded ``9`` index is out of range.

Comment: But I have more than 9 columns on that Grid View.